# SQL query to populate relational combo php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Query: Network

I am having 2 Combobox ( Country and Network), i need to populate Network combo on the basis of item selected in Country combo.

Table1: Network

```
Platform    Network       Location_ID
Platform 1  Operator 1     56
Platform 1  Operator 2     59
```

Table2 : Location

```
Location_ID     City    Country
56           Hong Kong   Hong Kong
109         Tafuna       American Samoa
59          Delhi        India
```

Help me to write sql query for same please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $query = "SELECT DISTINCT Network FROM Network".
            "INNER JOIN Location on Location.Location_ID =     Netwrok.Location_Id".
            "WHERE Location.Country = 'countryName' ";

Answer (score 1):

Bind your country dropdown to Location_ID and Country of Location table as value and text respectively. 
You can use the following query for binding Location -

```
select Location_ID, Country from Location
```

And then for binding your Network combo box, use the following query :

```
select Network, Platform    
from Network
where Location_ID = @Location_ID
```

`@Location_ID` is the selected value in your country dropdown list.

*Note* : Populate your network combo in the change event of country combo box.